# How to add intellisense for custom xml in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to add intellisense to Visual Studio 2015 for custom xml framework in which I have custom tags with different attributes and allowed values.
For example, if we add alignment attribute then intellisense should show valid values to add.

Visual Studio intellisense for html:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a XSD Schema for files then you have to these [sample files](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/desktopdev/mstech/vs2012/intellisense-for-custom-xml-in/):

**AwesomeFile.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AwesomeList>
    <AwesomeItem AwesomenessFactor="11">
        <AwesomeType>Is Awesome</AwesomeType>
    </AwesomeItem>
</AwesomeList>
```

**Awesome.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="MyAwesomeSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="AwesomeLevel">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="5"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="10"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="11"></xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="AwesomeElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AwesomeType" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="AwesomenessFactor" type="AwesomeLevel" use="required"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="AwesomeList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="AwesomeItem" type="AwesomeElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Results are:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Asif ali, I will try and I am sure that it will work.